# Pytorch function name demystification: gels for least squares estimation

Tags: naming, pytorch

What does "gels" stand for in Pytorch?
It solves **least squares**, but what does the name stand for?

It is hard to get comfortable with a function without getting its name and it is surprising that these are not explained in the documentation.

Comment: If I had to guess (especially for the first two letters), it stands for something like **G**PU-**E**val-**L**east-**S**quares.

Comment: Really? Do you think the G is related to GPU? It should work with CPU too. I was guessing about Generalized something...

Comment: That sounds good, too. I really have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gels` is actually a function from LAPACK (Linear Algebra Package) and stands for **GE**neralalized **L**east **S**quares meaning that it works on [general matrices](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/blas.html):

> **General matrix**
>
> A general real or complex m by n matrix is represented by a real or complex matrix of size (m, n).